# Recommended workflow for making a Google Play application available to in-house testers

Tags: android, testing, google-play, workflow

I am working on an Android application (published in Google Play), which undergoes a great deal of bug fixing right now, and this results in a plenitude of versions that need being tested, more often than not - simultaneously.

At first I wanted to use the Alpha Testing feature as a means to exposing these versions to in-house testers, but it seems that only one version of the app (ie. one bugfix) can be published as alpha at one time.

Is this correct? Or is there a way to allow testers to pick between various alphas to install?

If this approach is wrong, what's the way it should be done? Just uploading APKs on some server and sharing links with testers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your apha testing program can be done in two ways:

---

1. Distribute your apk through the Play Store as an alpha release. The catch is that you cannot have your users choose apks for testing. You can only have one at a time although you can upload multiple apks[you will be asked to deactivate the active apk].
2. Distribute your apks through a server. You could add password protection and all.

---

RECOMMENDED option is number 2 if you're interested in testing different versions overall.

Comment: Could you please check the answer as accepted if you're happy with it? WOuld be nice to get reputation... :)

Comment: Sure, it's accepted now. I always give it a while to allow for any other answers to come up. But it seems that you are spot on, thanks.